# Vegas Pro: imported m2ts missing audio

Tags: audio, vegas, dts

I'm editing a clip for my friend's wedding, when I try to import a .m2ts file from my Blu-Ray disk, only the video has been added. seems Vegas doesn't recognize the audio format...

I'm sure the file is with Audio(using mediainfo and player to directly play that file), and I tried some other .mp4 file which works file.
The Audio format is DTS. and I'm using Vegas Pro 12.

Could any body give any suggestions, thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vegas Pro 12 doesn't support DTS audio, period.

If anyone runs in the same problem, here is my work around.

1. Use video splitter to crop the clip you want from the .m2ts file. There are a bunch of tools.
2. Convert it to something Vegas Pro recognized, I personally use [Microsoft Expression encoder](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18974) because is free.